# Center revealing slider background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm making a reveal on mouse move effect on my site to have two divs with background images on top of each other. As the mouse moves, the width of the left one changes accordingly.

[Works but not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDjnr.jpg)

The problem is I want to center the background image regardless of the viewport width (I want it to be responsive). **But when I set a background-position-x: center** on the image, I get this unwanted effect of the left image being left behind instead of being aligned with the behind image.

[Unintended effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4z6F.jpg)

Here is my code:

HTML

```html
        <div class="fox-wrapper">
            <div id="full-fox"></div>
            <div id="empty-fox"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```css
.fox-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
}

.fox-wrapper #full-fox, .fox-wrapper #empty-fox {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* "left" (in front) image */
.fox-wrapper #full-fox {
    background-image: url("../page-media/fox-dashed.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    z-index: 2;
}

/* "right" (behind) image */
.fox-wrapper #empty-fox {
    background: url("../page-media/bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;

}
```

JS

```js
document.onmousemove = e => {
    const fullFox = document.getElementById("full-fox");

    let x = e.clientX;
    let width = window.innerWidth;

    let percent = 100 * x / width

    fullFox.style.width = `${percent}%`;

}
```

**Codepen demo:**
https://codepen.io/davefoxxo/pen/ZEMrXEq

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet here, codepen or a site that you like? It would be easier to test fixes for your implementation that way, since we do not have the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I got your problem, its simple just change your CSS a bit,

Write this...

```
.img-wrapper #full-img {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486870591958-9b9d0d1dda99?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: fixed;
    background-position-y: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

instead of this...

```
.img-wrapper #full-img {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486870591958-9b9d0d1dda99?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I appreciate the comment. This seems to almost work, but it doesn't line up the two images. I updated my codepen to have the two images be identical except with one hue rotated to illustrate my point. Thank you

Comment: then simply change the #empty-img CSS too with these same lines

    background-position-x: fixed;
    background-position-y: center;

Comment: UPDATE: I got it working, but I had to change my ideology completely. Instead of using background-images, I used regular images with width / height 100%, and overflow hidden. To make it work, I set `object-fit: cover` and `object-position: 50% 50%` on both images, so that it covers the entire thing while being centered, exactly how I wanted. And to make one image reveal over the other on mouse move, I used the `clip-path` property in my JS instead of changing the width. Thanks everyone for your contribution! Link to working demo: https://codepen.io/davefoxxo/pen/BaOrazq

Answer (score 0):

One way to make images responsive based on their container is with the `object-fit` CSS property. You can use it with `object-fit: cover;` to keep the aspect ratio of the image and fill the given dimension. The image will be clipped to fit. You can view a demo and more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp